# how to fix User' object has no attribute 'is_active'?

Tags: flask

my login_user(user) function is't working, every time i login this error raise AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'

i think my user_loader function always return none

here is my models.py

```
from flask_login import UserMixin 
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db,login_manager


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return  User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

and here is my route

```
@app.route("/login",methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password,form.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            flash(f'You have been loged in','success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash(f'cheack email and password','danger')
    return render_template('Login.html', title='login', form=form)
```

Flask_blog/flaskblog/routes.py", line 60, in login
login_user(user)

Comment: I don't see an is_active attribute on that User class.

Comment: yes because i inherent this attribute from UserMixin

Comment: Ah yes my bad, strange. What happens if you do a 'dir()` on the user object returned to see what attributes and methods it has?

Comment: thank you i just realized that i had two models.py files :))))

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same trouble, but i fixed it by using following code.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(phone=form.phone.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

models:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __bind_key__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=True, nullable=False) 
    IDcard = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.String(3), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not define an AnonymousUser using the [AnonymousMixin](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/mixins.html)

```
login_manager.anonymous_user = AnonymousUser
```

as illustrated in [this project](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/shopyo/blob/dev/shopyo/modules/admin/models.py)